# Multi line log parsing for service times in PHP/Python

Tags: php, python, multiline

What's the best way to parse a multi line log file that require contextual knowledge from previous lines in php and/or python?

ex.

```
 Date    Time    ID    Call

1/1/10 00:00:00 1234 Start
1/1/10 00:00:01 1234 ServiceCall A Starts
1/1/10 00:00:05 1234 ServiceCall B Starts
1/1/10 00:00:06 1234 ServiceCall A Finishes
1/1/10 00:00:09 1234 ServiceCall B Finishes
1/1/10 00:00:10 1234 Stop
```

Each log line will have a unique id to bind it to a session but each consecutive set of lines is not guaranteed to be from the same session.

The ultimate goal is to find out how long each transaction took and how long each sub transaction took.

I'd love to use a library if one already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two different ways of doing this.

1) You can use a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to process the file line by line.  When you hit a Start line, mark the time.  When you hit a Stop line with the same ID, diff the time and report.

2) Use PHP's [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) with the m modifier to match all the text from each start/stop line set, then just look at the first and last lines of each match string returned.

In both cases, I would verify the IDs match to prevent against matching different sets.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to create objects each time my parser encountered the start pattern with a new key.  I'm assuming,from your example that 1234 is a key such that all log lines which must be correlated together can be mapped to the state of one "thing" (object).

So you see the pattern to start tracking one of these and every time you see a log entry that relates to it you call methods for the type of event (state change) that these subsequent lines represent.

From your example these "log state" objects (for lack of a more apropos term) might contain a list or dictionary (or other container) for each ServiceCall (which I would expect would be another class of objects).

So the overall design would be a parser/dispatcher that reads the log, if the log item relates to some existing object (key) then the item is dispatched to the object which
can then further create its own (ServiceCall or other) objects and/or dispatch events to those or raise exceptions or invoke callbacks or call outs to other functions as needed.

Presumably you also will need to have some collection or final disposition handler which could be called by your log objects when the Stop events are dispatched to them.

I'd guess you'd also want to support some sort or status reporting method so that the application can enumerate all live (uncollected) objects to in response to signals or commands in some other channel (perhaps from a non-blocking check performed by the parser/dispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on a log parser I wrote a while ago, tailored to your log format.  (The general approach tracks pretty closely with Jim Dennis's description, although I used a defaultdict of lists to accumulate all the entries for any given session.)

```
from pyparsing import Suppress,Word,nums,restOfLine
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

def convertToDateTime(tokens):
    month,day,year,hh,mm,ss = tokens
    return datetime(year+2000, month, day, hh,mm,ss)

# define building blocks for parsing and processing log file entries
SLASH,COLON = map(Suppress,"/:")
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
date = integer + (SLASH + integer)*2
time = integer + (COLON + integer)*2
timestamp = date + time
timestamp.setParseAction(convertToDateTime)

# define format of a single line in the log file
logEntry = timestamp("timestamp") + integer("sessionid") + restOfLine("descr")

# summarize calls into single data structure
calls = defaultdict(list)
for logline in log:
    entry = logEntry.parseString(logline)
    calls[entry.sessionid].append(entry)

# first pass to find start/end time for each call
for sessionid in sorted(calls):
    calldata = calls[sessionid]
    print sessionid, calldata[-1].timestamp - calldata[0].timestamp
```

For your data, this prints out:

```
1234 0:00:10
```

You can process each session's list of entries with a similar approach to tease apart the sub-transactions.